# Sending files to email id?

Tags: android

I am trying to send files from a specific folder inside sdcard "VCFFiles". I did all things correctly. It worked once but again when I run this app its showing force close.What I did in my project is I made 5 radiobuttons and text them as the files are listed inside "VCFFiles" folder. Whan anyradiobutton will be clicked, respective vcf file will be sent to the email entered in the edittext on clicking send button.following is my code:

```
public class SendActivity extends Activity{
    private static final int PICK_IMAGE = 1;
    EditText email;
    TextView add_manage;
    Button send;
    RadioGroup vcfgroup;
    RadioButton vcfButton;
    String filepath="";
    static File filevcf;
    static Context mContext;
    RadioButton vcf1;
    RadioButton vcf2;
    RadioButton vcf3;
    RadioButton vcf4;
    RadioButton vcf5;
    ProgressDialog dialog;
    String success;
    String message;
    String response;
    String data;
    File f;
    String radio;
    ArrayList<String> array;
//  String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.send);


        email = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.emailid);
        send = (Button)findViewById(R.id.send);
        add_manage = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.add_manage);
        vcfgroup = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.vcfgroup);
        vcf1 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.vcf1);
        vcf2 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.vcf2);
        vcf3 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.vcf3);
        vcf4 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.vcf4);
        vcf5 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.vcf5);
        send = (Button)findViewById(R.id.send);
        // get selected radio button from radioGroup


        radio = vcf1.getText().toString();



        //get file names and set it in radio buttons
        if(!isExternalStorageAvailable() || isExternalStorageReadOnly()){

        }else{
        new EventListTask2().execute(this);
        }
        //send vcf files to the server
        send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int selectedId = vcfgroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

                vcf1 =(RadioButton)findViewById(selectedId);
                try{
                    f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/VCFFiles/"+vcf1.getText().toString());
                    filepath = f.getPath();



                if(email.getText().length()!=0){
                    dialog = ProgressDialog.show(SendActivity.this,
                            "Sending", "Please wait...", true);
                    new EventListTask1().execute();
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You may have not entered emailid or selected wrong file!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                }catch(Exception e){

                }
            }
        });

        add_manage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent in = new Intent(SendActivity.this,AddContactActivity.class);
                startActivity(in);
            }
        });



    }




    public ArrayList<String> GetFiles() {
        ArrayList<String> MyFiles = new ArrayList<String>();
        File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/VCFFiles");

        f.mkdirs();
        File[] files = f.listFiles();
        if (files.length == 0)
            return null;
        else {
            for (int i=0; i<5; i++) 
                if(files[i].getPath().endsWith(".vcf")){
                MyFiles.add(files[i].getName());
                }
        }

        return MyFiles;
    }
```

inside EventListTask2 class I am fetching files from "VCFFIles" using GetFiles() function and associating the name with each radiobutton's name.The code inside is shown below:

```
RadioButton radioset[] = {vcf1, vcf2, vcf3, vcf4, vcf5};
                if(GetFiles().size()!=0){
                array=GetFiles();
                for(int i=0;i<array.size();i++){
                    radioset[i].setText(array.get(i));
                }}else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You have no vcf files saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
```

Following is log of the app:

```
03-18 18:41:17.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1598): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-18 18:41:17.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1598): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-18 18:41:17.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1598):     at com.example.mycontactdetails.SendActivity$EventListTask1.onPostExecute(SendActivity.java:321)
03-18 18:41:17.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1598):     at com.example.mycontactdetails.SendActivity$EventListTask1.onPostExecute(SendActivity.java:1)
03-18 18:41:17.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1598):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
03-18 18:41:17.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1598):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
03-18 18:41:17.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1598):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
03-18 18:41:17.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1598):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-18 18:41:17.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1598):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-18 18:41:17.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1598):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
03-18 18:41:17.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1598):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-18 18:41:17.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1598):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-18 18:41:17.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1598):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
03-18 18:41:17.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1598):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
03-18 18:41:17.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1598):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-18 18:53:12.560: E/IOException(1648): IO error: /mnt/sdcard/VCFFiles/Empty (Permission denied)
03-18 18:53:12.560: E/IOException(1648): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/VCFFiles/Empty (Permission denied)
03-18 18:53:12.560: E/IOException(1648):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSFileSystem.openImpl(Native Method)
03-18 18:53:12.560: E/IOException(1648):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSFileSystem.open(OSFileSystem.java:152)
03-18 18:53:12.560: E/IOException(1648):    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:82)
03-18 18:53:12.560: E/IOException(1648):    at com.example.mycontactdetails.SendActivity$Utils.PostDataToFavoriteUser(SendActivity.java:182)
03-18 18:53:12.560: E/IOException(1648):    at com.example.mycontactdetails.SendActivity$EventListTask1.doInBackground(SendActivity.java:310)
03-18 18:53:12.560: E/IOException(1648):    at com.example.mycontactdetails.SendActivity$EventListTask1.doInBackground(SendActivity.java:1)
03-18 18:53:12.560: E/IOException(1648):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
03-18 18:53:12.560: E/IOException(1648):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
03-18 18:53:12.560: E/IOException(1648):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
03-18 18:53:12.560: E/IOException(1648):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
03-18 18:53:12.560: E/IOException(1648):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
03-18 18:53:12.560: E/IOException(1648):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
03-18 18:53:12.630: E/AndroidRuntime(1648): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-18 18:53:12.630: E/AndroidRuntime(1648): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-18 18:53:12.630: E/AndroidRuntime(1648):     at com.example.mycontactdetails.SendActivity$EventListTask1.onPostExecute(SendActivity.java:321)
03-18 18:53:12.630: E/AndroidRuntime(1648):     at com.example.mycontactdetails.SendActivity$EventListTask1.onPostExecute(SendActivity.java:1)
03-18 18:53:12.630: E/AndroidRuntime(1648):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
03-18 18:53:12.630: E/AndroidRuntime(1648):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
03-18 18:53:12.630: E/AndroidRuntime(1648):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
03-18 18:53:12.630: E/AndroidRuntime(1648):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-18 18:53:12.630: E/AndroidRuntime(1648):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-18 18:53:12.630: E/AndroidRuntime(1648):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
03-18 18:53:12.630: E/AndroidRuntime(1648):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-18 18:53:12.630: E/AndroidRuntime(1648):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-18 18:53:12.630: E/AndroidRuntime(1648):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
03-18 18:53:12.630: E/AndroidRuntime(1648):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
03-18 18:53:12.630: E/AndroidRuntime(1648):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-18 19:00:13.010: E/IOException(1676): IO error: /mnt/sdcard/VCFFiles/Empty (Permission denied)
03-18 19:00:13.010: E/IOException(1676): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/VCFFiles/Empty (Permission denied)
03-18 19:00:13.010: E/IOException(1676):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSFileSystem.openImpl(Native Method)
03-18 19:00:13.010: E/IOException(1676):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSFileSystem.open(OSFileSystem.java:152)
03-18 19:00:13.010: E/IOException(1676):    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:82)
03-18 19:00:13.010: E/IOException(1676):    at com.example.mycontactdetails.SendActivity$Utils.PostDataToFavoriteUser(SendActivity.java:183)
03-18 19:00:13.010: E/IOException(1676):    at com.example.mycontactdetails.SendActivity$EventListTask1.doInBackground(SendActivity.java:311)
03-18 19:00:13.010: E/IOException(1676):    at com.example.mycontactdetails.SendActivity$EventListTask1.doInBackground(SendActivity.java:1)
03-18 19:00:13.010: E/IOException(1676):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
03-18 19:00:13.010: E/IOException(1676):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
03-18 19:00:13.010: E/IOException(1676):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
03-18 19:00:13.010: E/IOException(1676):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
03-18 19:00:13.010: E/IOException(1676):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
03-18 19:00:13.010: E/IOException(1676):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
03-18 19:00:13.090: E/AndroidRuntime(1676): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-18 19:00:13.090: E/AndroidRuntime(1676): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-18 19:00:13.090: E/AndroidRuntime(1676):     at com.example.mycontactdetails.SendActivity$EventListTask1.onPostExecute(SendActivity.java:322)
03-18 19:00:13.090: E/AndroidRuntime(1676):     at com.example.mycontactdetails.SendActivity$EventListTask1.onPostExecute(SendActivity.java:1)
03-18 19:00:13.090: E/AndroidRuntime(1676):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
03-18 19:00:13.090: E/AndroidRuntime(1676):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
03-18 19:00:13.090: E/AndroidRuntime(1676):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
03-18 19:00:13.090: E/AndroidRuntime(1676):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-18 19:00:13.090: E/AndroidRuntime(1676):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-18 19:00:13.090: E/AndroidRuntime(1676):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
03-18 19:00:13.090: E/AndroidRuntime(1676):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-18 19:00:13.090: E/AndroidRuntime(1676):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-18 19:00:13.090: E/AndroidRuntime(1676):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
03-18 19:00:13.090: E/AndroidRuntime(1676):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
03-18 19:00:13.090: E/AndroidRuntime(1676):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I am not getting what's going wrong? Any help would be grateful.

Comment: If you are getting a FC post your Log

Comment: Please post the logcat.

Comment: added logcat please check.

Comment: @RotaryHeart,Class Stacker : I have updated my question. Please check.

Comment: You added permission to Manifest?

Comment: @RotaryHeart I have added following permissions:

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

Comment: FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/VCFFiles/Empty (Permission denied) Are you sure the file exists? you could call file.exists(); to be sure before trying to do anything

Comment: @RotaryHeart That's why I have put this check before getting file from "VCFFiles":
if(GetFiles().size()!=0)